# iOS Swift: Returning a 'Bool' in a function that shows alert confirmation message

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm creating a function that returns a boolean. But Swift shows me the error:

> Missing return in a function expected to return 'Bool'

My function doesn't directly return a 'Bool', it has some conditions, like if user clicks "OK" button then it should return true, if "Cancel" then return false. Can someone please tell me how can I fix this issue? Please see the code below for your reference:

```
func showConfirmationAlert(title: String!, message: String!) -> Bool {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        let alertController=UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let okButton=UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (okSelected) -> Void in
            return true
        }
        let cancelButton=UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (cancelSelected) -> Void in
            return false
        }
        alertController.addAction(okButton)
        alertController.addAction(cancelButton)
        if self.presentedViewController == nil {
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You will need to ensure all exit paths in your method do have an explicit return statement with a boolean value true/false. Observe that towards the end of your function you don't have a return statement

Comment: Because there's no condition based on which I can have the return statement. If I put 'return false' at the end, it will always return false even if user clicks 'Ok'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think you want some thing like this

```
func showConfirmationAlert(title: String!, message: String!,success: (() -> Void)? , cancel: (() -> Void)?) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
  let alertController = UIAlertController(title:title,
    message: message,
    preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

  let cancelLocalized = NSLocalizedString("cancelButton", tableName: "activity", comment:"")
  let okLocalized = NSLocalizedString("viewDetails.button", tableName: "Localizable", comment:"")

  let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelLocalized,
    style: .Cancel) {
      action -> Void in cancel?()
  }
  let successAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: okLocalized,
    style: .Default) {
      action -> Void in success?()
  }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(successAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  })
}
showConfirmationAlert("mytitle", message: "body", success: { () -> Void in
  print("success")
  }) { () -> Void in
    print("user canceled")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` statements are inside a closure, which is part of `dispatch_async`. Consider the closure to be a separate function, and it is therefore clear that those statements are within that separate function, and therefore `showConfirmationAlert` has no `return` statement of its own.

Rather than have the `dispatch_async` inside `showConfirmationAlert`, it should surround whatever is calling the function. Nevertheless, you will probably have to deal with the fact that you're dealing with multiple threads.